# How can I create a ModelView in Flask-Admin whose url contains a variable prefix and use that variable to do the initial filtering?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have the following (simplified) structure in version one of an app that I'm working on porting over much of the logic to Flask-Admin for version two:

- Portals

  - This is the base resource for all other resources
  - Route `/` leads to a list view of portals
  - Route `/new` leads to the form for creating a portal
  - Route `/<portal_slug>/edit` leads to the form for updating a portal
- Accounts

  - Relate directly to a portal, so v1 of the application routes are as follows
  - Route `/<portal_slug>/accounts` leads to a list view
  - Route `/<portal_slug>/accounts/new` leads to the form for creating an account
  - Route `/<portal_slug>/accounts/<account_id>[/edit]` leads to the form for updating an account

My reasoning for the structure is for user-friendly urls, plus it only seems logical to branch out from portal since it's the main resource for the application.

With the above url structure I have a `url_value_preprocessor` function that loads the entities into Flask's `g` variable for use in the views.

```py
@app.url_value_preprocessor
def load_url_objects(endpoint, values):
    if not values:
        return
    if "portal_slug" in values:
        g.portal = Portal.query.filter_by(slug=values.pop("portal_slug", None)).first()
        if g.portal:
            # save portal_id to session for use elsewhere
            session["portal_id"] = g.portal.id
            if "account_id" in values:
                g.account = g.portal.accounts.filter_by(id=values.pop("account_id", None)).first()
```

## My Questions

How can I maintain this url structure when using Flask-Admin? How can I implement this sort of behavior?

**Obstacle 1**: For all views attached to a Portal (Accounts, Reports, Jobs, etc.) the `portal_slug` is a filter that needs to be applied *prior* to list view rendering. This is because each portal will have additional custom fields that need to be rendered in list view on top of static fields that are present for all portals.

**Obstacle 2**: Providing a dropdown in the navbar (instead of in the content area) to allow switching the portal no matter what view the user is in. This would also be used to select the initial portal (or maybe have it default to the first portal) whenever clicking any of the navbar links to be taken to views that are attached to a portal. That's what I use the `session["portal_id"] = g.portal.id` for above, in order to make the navigation between tabs easy for the end-user (maintaining the last-viewed portal).

**Obstacle 3?**: I imagine getting all the urls to reflect this behavior whenever sorting, searching, filtering would be extremely difficult. Or maybe more likely I just can't figure out all the functions that I need to override.

## Minimal Working Example of Structure

```py
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask, session, g
from flask_admin import Admin
from sqlalchemy import event
from slugify import slugify

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
admin = Admin(app, url="/", template_mode="bootstrap4")

class Portal(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "portals"
 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    display_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    accounts = db.relationship("Account", backref="portal", lazy="dynamic", cascade="all, delete")
    
    @staticmethod
    def slugify(target, new_value, old_value, initiator):
        if new_value and (not target.slug or new_value != old_value):
            new_slug = slugify(new_value, lowercase=True, max_length=20, word_boundary=True, save_order=True)
            target.slug = new_slug

class Account(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "accounts"
 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    portal_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("portals.id"), nullable=False)
    client_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

event.listen(Portal.display_name, "set", Portal.slugify, retval=False)

@app.shell_context_processor
def load_url_objects(endpoint, values):
    if not values:
        return
    if "portal_slug" in values:
        g.portal = Portal.query.filter_by(slug=values.pop("portal_slug", None)).first()
        if g.portal:
            # save portal_id to session for top navbar link routes
            session["portal_id"] = g.portal.id
            if "account_id" in values:
                g.account = g.portal.accounts.filter_by(id=values.pop("account_id", None)).first()

class PortalView(ModelView): pass  # /portals
class AccountView(ModelView): pass  # currently /accounts, but need it to be /<portal_slug>/accounts for all links related to account(s)

admin.add_view(PortalView(Portal, db.session, name="Portals", endpoint="portals"))
admin.add_view(AccountView(Account, db.session, name="Accounts", endpoint="accounts"))

@app.before_first_request
def prep_db():
    db.create_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.config.update({
        "SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS": False,
        "SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI": "sqlite:///:memory:"
    })
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I'm having a hard visualizing the problem. Do you mind providing a link to a gist/dummy github project with what you are trying to do?

Comment: Added general structure. Comment on the ModelView is where I need help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and I solved it by overwriting the get_query and get_query_count method to have my index_view filter and overwriting my endpoint.

You had your route as /<portal_slug>/accounts/<account_id>[/edit]- I would suggest you @expose("/<account_id>/edit and rewriting your edit_view function

```
class PostView(ModelVieW):
  ...
  all your main required code goes here 
  including your expose..

  @expose("/<account_id>/edit")
  def my_edit_view(self):
     ... ...
     you need to take the account_id param and pass it
     to flask.request as param id=<account_id>, this is
     how flask-admin read the id.

     return super().edit_view()

class PostPublishView(PostView):

    def is_visible(self):
        return False

    def get_query(self):
        return self.session.query(self.model).filter(self.model.status=='publish')

    def get_count_query(self):
        return self.session.query(func.count('*')).filter(self.model.status=='publish')


admin.add_view(PostPublishView(Post, db.session, name="Publish", endpoint='/post/publish'))
admin.add_view(PostView(Post, db.session, name='Post', endpoint='post'))
```